# How do I get default values in access form to disappear when I enter the field?

Tags: ms-access, default-value

I have assigned a default value to a label box in Property Sheet/data/default value. 
When I create a new entry via the form, the default value shows up but then I have to select it and delete it in order to enter the correct value.

Is there a way to automatically make the default value vanish when I enter the field? (like on this page where you are ask for you email : http://www.boogiejack.com/form_trick3.html)

I am using the default value to display a hint about what data should be enter in this label. I will never keep the default value in my actual database. My default value is not a permanent value.

I though about adding in virtual basic something like :

```
IF text = default value THEN delete
```

but I am a newbie and can figuring out how to do it or even if this is the correct way of doing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `Default` property (Data tab) and use the `Format` property (Format tab) to specify text that will be displayed when the Text Box contains a Null value. For Text fields, there are two parts to the `Format` property string:

```
format_to_use_when_not_null;format_to_use_when_null
```

so you could use something like this

```
@;"(Please enter something here.)"
```

That text will appear until the user clicks inside the Text Box (or tabs into it and starts typing).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a vicious one to find. For sure, it will be very handy for all my next forms. Thanks again Gord!

Comment: Hi Gordon, a question, What is the equivalent of this for a combo box? I cannot seem to find this information anywhere.

Comment: @Rym - The most common approach is to set up the combo box so the default entry says something like "Please select..." and the real values follow. I don't recall there being a "null format" option for combo boxes like there is for text boxes.